# return only date from primefaces p:calendar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I trying to return date like that " 9/10/2013 " only without time or naming dayes

but when I use

```
<p:calendar  value="#{studentQuery.from}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true" display="inline"/>
```

it return :

```
Thu Sep 12 00:00:00 EET 2013
```

how to fix that to return date only like : " 9/10/2013 " using primefaces 3.5 with jsf 2

Comment: Where does it return that? Do you mean the variable in the bean? That pattern only affects the field where primefaces shows the selected date. same pattern on outputtext and you see it with the same pattern.

Comment: yes at bean with Date object type , i use system.out.println

Comment: so you need to use some DateFormat in java too.

Comment: It's because the date object always has the same outputPattern if you just call it with prinln. The Date object itself is data, not a datestring.

Comment: If you want to print it prettily in console, use DateFormat or any similar dateformatter. If you want it prettily on the page, use outputText and the same patter.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

 System.out.print(format.format(dateObject));
```

In JSF:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">  
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>  
        </h:outputText>
```

roughly like this.

Comment: <f:convertDateTime> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder

Comment: This answer is NOT compatible with Primefaces 3.5 !

Comment: interesting. Should you try with type="date" in the converter. Rather i'm  interested, why does the primefaces version affect this solution? This printing includes no primefaces components.

Comment: Could not convert 'java.text.SimpleDateFormat@7c669100' to a string.

Comment: are you giving the format itself as a parameter? And not the Date object?